# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency props with redux functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having a ton of react hooks a missing dependency warnings for my redux functions that are called in useEffect to fetch data. The [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) and [dan abramov's post](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) about this issue doesn't help me so much on what to do. Since, in summary, the recommendations are  ;

- move the function inside the useEffect if it is used in an effect only (I would rather not because I am using these functions elsewhere as well.)
- move the function outside the component if it is not using any props or state ( they are already declared in their own store and I bring them to the component's context via connecting tag. And so they appear on the props object of the component. So this solution is also not applicable.
- wrap them with useCallback so you can add them in the dependency array and it won't lead to an infinite loop because the functions will not get a new reference on each render. ( this sounds a little bit hacky solution to me. But if not please enlighten me. So it will look like this;

```js
const { fetchMe } = props
useEffect(() => {
  fetchMe()
}, [])
```

will turn into this

```js
const { fetchMe } = props
const initFetchMe = useCallback(() => {
   return dispatch(fetchMe())
}, [dispatch])


useEffect(() => {
   initFetchMe();
}, [initFetchMe]);
```

When I look at the stackoverflow some candidate solution for this to refactor connect tag with redux hooks (useDispatch and useSelector) I am more leaning towards this solution but I couldn't find a good migration guide, I don't want to be introducing lots of bugs at once to the repo. So this example component:

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import Stats from '../components/Stats'
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getEmployeesTotal} from '../stores/employees'
import {getVisitorsTotal} from '../stores/visitors'
import {getCardsTotal} from '../stores/cards'

function SimpleStats(props) {
  const {t} = useTranslation()

  useEffect(() => {
    props.getEmployeesTotal()
    props.getCardsTotal()
    props.getVisitorsTotal()
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row quick-stats justify-content-md-center">
            <Stats
              className="col"
              value={
                props.get_employees_total !== null ? props.get_employees_total.meta.total : '...'
              }
              description={t('stats.EmployeesTotal')}
            />
            <Stats
              className="col"
              value={
                props.get_visitors_total !== null ? props.get_visitors_total.meta.total : '...'
              }
              description={t('stats.VisitorsTotal')}
            />
            <Stats
              className="col"
              value={props.get_cards_total !== null ? props.get_cards_total.meta.total : '...'}
              description={t('stats.CardsTotal')}
            />
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  get_employees_total: state.employees.get_employees_total.success,
  get_visitors_total: state.visitors.get_visitors_total.success,
  get_cards_total: state.cards.get_cards_total.success,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getEmployeesTotal,
  getVisitorsTotal,
  getCardsTotal,
})(SimpleStats)
```

becomes this:

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import Stats from '../components/Stats'
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getEmployeesTotal} from '../stores/employees'
import {getVisitorsTotal} from '../stores/visitors'
import {getCardsTotal} from '../stores/cards'

function SimpleStats(props) {
  const {t} = useTranslation()

  const get_employees_total = useSelector((state)=>state.employees.get_employees_total.success)
  const get_visitors_total = useSelector((state) => state.visitors.get_visitors_total.success )
  const get_cards_total = useSelector((state) => state.cards.get_cards_total.success)

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getEmployeesTotal())
  dispatch(getCardsTotal())
  dispatch(getVisitorsTotal())
}, [dispatch])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row quick-stats justify-content-md-center">
            <Stats
              className="col"
              value={
                props.get_employees_total !== null ? props.get_employees_total.meta.total : '...'
              }
              description={t('stats.EmployeesTotal')}
            />
            <Stats
              className="col"
              value={
                props.get_visitors_total !== null ? props.get_visitors_total.meta.total : '...'
              }
              description={t('stats.VisitorsTotal')}
            />
            <Stats
              className="col"
              value={props.get_cards_total !== null ? props.get_cards_total.meta.total : '...'}
              description={t('stats.CardsTotal')}
            />
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default SimpleStats
```

Would you enlighten me on which solution is better? Does my migration to redux-hooks have problems?

Comment: Start using redux hooks . As they are optimized and easier to read as well .

Comment: @Shyam optimized in what sense? would you elaborate. I see on react-redux documentation that it is recommended to do switch but the reasoning behind is about rather if you are using typescript. and they also say it will have consequences re-rendering behaviour to be careful about. That's my concern for hooks migration.